# How to set proxy pass for react app on nginx?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My react app has got different routes to consume different functionalities

e.x.

```
localhost:3000,
localhost:3000/Dashboard,
localhost:3000/Hub,
localhost:3000/Person
```

etc....

I wanted to configure the react app routes in the nginx in the production environment. What I have actually done so far in the nginx configuration at production env is,

```
server_name api.vesta-project.net;

location /vqcc {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

My problem here is with the current settings, the homepage works well when I say "`api.vesta-project.net/vqcc`". Whereas, when I click a button that navigates to `/Dashboard`. I get `404 error` as it does not append "vqcc" to the path in the react app internally thus it becomes like  `api.vesta-project.net/Dashboard`" when inspecting the request which is wrong per nginx conf. So I need a solution whenever the client make a request, it should append "`vqcc`" to the path so that it will become a valid url as per nginx routes.

e.x when client request for `api.vesta-project.net/Dashboard`, it should become

```
api.vesta-project.net/vqcc/Dashboard
```

Pls help me if I can handle this at nginx or package.json without being changing any routes in the react app internally

Answer (score 2):

You can try rewriting the uri in catch-all location.

```
location / {
    rewrite /(.*) /vqcc/$1;
}

location /vqcc{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Chang but the problem is I can't re-write the base uri ('/') because it is already been consumed by an another service running in the same environment.